# extracting a basic sequence from non relatively compact set

Tags: functional-analysis

Le $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $T : X \rightarrow Y$ a bounded operator which is not weak-compact. Hence $A = \{y = Tx : x \in X, \|x\| \leq 1\}$ is not relatively weakly compact.

How can I extract a basic sequence from $A$ ?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "basic sequence"? Do you mean a (countably infinite) basis? If so, what kind (Schauder, Hamel, Markuschevich, etc)?

Comment: Sorry, not "basic" but basis. I mean a Schauder basis.